# what's different about sessionDAO's and securityManager's cacheManager in shiro ,can I use same one

Tags: shiro

what's different about sessionDAO's cacheManager and securityManager's cacheManager in shiro ,can I use same one .
my cacheManager is redis cache implementation    。

```
public class CacheSessionDAO extends EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO implements SessionDAO {
```

when I config sessionDAO and securityManager's use same one cacheManager . The readSession method will  often called .
I want to know what's happed?

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a CacheManager to you SecurityManager, the security manager will propagate it to other supporting objects (Realms, etc).

While you could use different cache managers for each type of object, it is common to use the same one.